# Record in dm_exec_cached_plans but not in dm_exec_query_stats

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to identify how many times a proc has been executed.

When I search by plan handle, I find a record in dm_exec_cached_plans but not in dm_exec_query_stats.  All of the documentation I can find indicates that if a record is in  dm_exec_cached_plans then it should always have a corresponding record in  dm_exec_query_stats.

Does anyone know a scenario where this would not be true?

Comment: `select * from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans where plan_handle not in (select plan_handle from sys.dm_exec_query_stats)` returns lots of results for me.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that- if a record is in dm_exec_cached_plans then it should always have a corresponding record in dm_exec_query_stats ?
Actually `dm_exec_cached_plans` has a record for every compiled plan in the plan cache, and `dm_exec_query_stats` can have a record for every query statement in the corresponding cached plan. `dm_exec_query_stats` can be empty for a cached plan of cache object types "Parse Tree" or "CLR Compiled Proc" or for objects such as system stored procedures, ad hoc queries, prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

What about using sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701%28v=sql.100%29.aspx